# Error with Bluetooth and PyBluez: "OSError: [Errno 97] Address family not supported by protocol"

Tags: debian, google-chrome-os, pybluez

I'm running into an error while trying to discover and connect to bluetooth devices. The error and script are below.

I'm running a python script on a Google Chromebook. Here is the error:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/bluetooth/bluez.py", line 19, in discover_devices
    device_id = _bt.hci_get_route()
OSError: [Errno 97] Address family not supported by protocol
```

The code is taken directly from PyBluez:

```
import bluetooth

nearby_devices = bluetooth.discover_devices(lookup_names=True)
print("Found {} devices.".format(len(nearby_devices)))

for addr, name in nearby_devices:
    print("  {} - {}".format(addr, name))
```

OS version:

```
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="11"
VERSION="11 (bullseye)"
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you